# Download and open a file by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a SPA.

I want to download a file (e.g. .xlsx) and open a "Open With" dialog like [this](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/65ea7b26-872a-4d0d-a91d-0dc3cf706c2e?upload=true), by javascript.
Or open the file on client's PC.

Is there a way to solve this?
I know javascript cannot access to local files without
`<input type="file">`.

I want any advice. (even THIS IS IMPOSSIBLE)

Comment: This may help you have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/open

Comment: Yes, you may specify applications to open a file via an **href** address. So after it is downloaded, do something such as `<a href="safari://google.com" target="_blank">Open Google in Safari</a> /* note safari:// */`. Yes, it is very possible.

Comment: Just paste that subject line into a web search...will find lots of results

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your SPA has an API? Well, you need to the direct the user to an API endpoint that will create and then send to the client the `.xlsx` file.

You can use the [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to control how the browser will open the file.

Kind regards,